# Mimic filled.contour with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, contour

I've been trying to mimic the output of `filled.contour` with ggplot's `geom_tile` and `geom_raster`. There seems to be some interpolation or something behind the scenes of `filled.contour` to fill in the gaps, especially in y-axis. Any idea how to make similar, nice looking plot with ggplot?

Data for example can be downloaded [here](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/9c4302cbf5c24701b73a98c01451e175/data.csv) (ShareCSV link).

Code for example:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("reshape2")


file <- file.choose()
data <- read.csv(file, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE,
                 colClasses=c("POSIXct", rep("numeric", 12)),
                 check.names=FALSE)

palette <- colorRampPalette(c("darkblue", "blue", "lightblue1",
                              "green", "yellow", "red", "darkred"))

# GGplot version
df <- melt(data, id.vars="Time", measure.vars=names(data)[-1])
names(df)[2:3] <- c("Channel", "Value")
df$Channel <- log10(as.numeric(as.character(df$Channel)))
df$Value <- log10(df$Value)


p <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Time, y=Channel, fill=Value)) +
  # geom_tile() +
  geom_raster() +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0, 0)) +
  scale_x_datetime(expand=c(0, 0)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=palette(100)) +
  theme_bw()

p

# Base version
Channel <- log10(as.numeric(names(data[-1])))
Value <- log10(data.matrix(data[, -1]))

filled.contour(x=data$Time, y=Channel, z=Value,
               color.palette=palette, nlevels=100)
```

I tried the following for `df` and it got pretty close but it's very compute intensive.

```
library("akima")

interpolation <- with(df, interp(x=Time, y=Channel, z=Value,
                      xo=seq(min(Time), max(Time), length.out=nrow(data)),
                      duplicate="mean"))

df<- interp2xyz(interpolation, data.frame=TRUE)
names(df) <- c("Time", "Channel", "Value")
df$Time <- as.POSIXct(df$Time, origin="1970-01-01")
```

Outcome:

[image]

Comment: have you looked at `geom_contour`?

Comment: @Richard Telford Not yet but I will

Comment: No luck with `geom_contour`/`stat_contour` so far.